# Play 2.4 (Java) : posting a form returns Unauthorized in IE11, works in Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer-11, playframework-2.4

I just migrated to Play 2.4.6 with activator 1.3.7.

I have  a secured controller that's handling a form. The form submission works well in Chrome, but in IE11, the http POST result is a 403 code (Unauthorized). I don't understand why this is happening. It is an intermittent problem : with the same user connected, sometimes the post works, sometimes it doesn't. Other posts from my application (on some other page) work ok.
Can somebody help ?

I use action composition for authorization and the automatic csrf filters that Play provides, which all have worked perfectly under play 2.3. They also work with play 2.4.6 in Chrome, I have followed the steps of the [CSRF configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaCsrf) ... I need to make it work in IE because of my user base.

Here is the controller :

```
@play.mvc.Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
@Authorize(minLevel=PermissionLevel.VENDOR)
public class SoumRapideFlexible extends Controller {
...
  public static Result save(){      
    Form<SoumFlex> boundForm = soumflexForm.bindFromRequest();

    if(boundForm.hasErrors()){          
        return badRequest(page.render(boundForm));
    }
    ... // else do stuff with the Soumflex object
  }
}
```

And here is the form, stripped down to the essential:

```
@(myForm: Form[SoumFlex])
@import helper._
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>                              
    <script data-main="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/main_soumflex")" 
src="@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/requirejs/require.js")"></script>              
</head>
<body>
    @form(routes.SoumRapideFlexible.save(), 'class -> "form-horizontal") {
        @CSRF.formField

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjet">Projet</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputProjet" name="inputProjet" placeholder="Nom du projet" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        //... and many other form fields in similar fashion...

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="soumettreSoum" value="Save">                   
    </div> <!-- resumeSoum -->
    }   
</div>                               
</body>
</html>
```

It is as if sometimes the user credentials are lost or the csrf token is not right... Anybody has an idea why I'd have such a behavior in IE11? Please help.

Comment: Can't add much insight, but in recent testing, I have found that [swagger](http://editor.swagger.io/) is very careful about CSRF, so testing from swagger has helped me iron out some CSRF issues in my apis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I used [this implementation of the global CSRF filter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaCsrf#Applying-a-global-CSRF-filter) but it gave me the problem outlined above.

Then I tried [this implementation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaHttpFilters#Using-filters) (replacing gzip by csrf) and the problem seems to have disappeared ! I think having a final property did the trick.